# In SceneKit we can not create PhysicalBody at every location, is that normal?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

At sceneView we have a big cube.

```
SCNBox(width: 10, height:10, length: 10, chamferRadius: 0)
```

We are placing spheres(radius = 1) on the six surfaces of that bigger cube.
Spheres have dynamic physicalBody.

Debugger mode is active with

```
sceneView.debugOptions = [.showPhysicsFields, .showPhysicsShapes]
```

When we run app we can see that only sphere with node position

```
SCNVector3(x:0, y: 0, z: 10.5)
```

seems to have body, only this one marked by debugger.
Also, only this sphere responds if a kinetic body touches it.

Is there something we are missing, why the spheres on other surfaces can not have physical body.

This is how I create spheres;

```
    var ball:[SCNSphere] = []
    var ballNode:[SCNSNode] = []

    var body:[SCNPhysicsBody] = []
    let pShape = SCNSphere()
        pShape.radius = 1
        pShape.segmentCount = 1


    for k in 0..<6 {

      ball.append(SCNSphere())
      ballNode.append(SCNSphere())
      ball[k].radius = 1
      ball[k].hunt.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
      ballNode[k]= SCNNode(geometry:ball[k])

      let shape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: pShape, options: nil)
      body.append(SCNPhysicsBody())
      body[k] = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: shape)
      body[k].isAffectedByGravity = false
      body[k].friction = 1
      body[k].restitution = 0.1
      body[k].angularDamping = 1
      ballNode[k].physicsBody = body[k] 

      let coors = createCoors(index: k)
      ballNode.position = SCNVector3(coors.x, coors.y, coors.z)

      bigBoxNode.addChildNode(ballNode[k]) 
   }
```

Comment: All nodes can have PhysicsBody attributes.  You can see all 6 spheres but only 1 reacts?  Can you attach a picture and/or show PhysicsBody attributes?

Comment: I noticed that only ball having active physical body the one on the surface looking to the camera. If I rotate cube and rerun code above after remove bodies the active ball changes to the one looking to the camera ????